# pod conflicting on flutter with this package video_editor

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, video-editing

```
[!] The 'Pods-Runner' target has frameworks with conflicting names: ffmpegkit.xcframework, libavcodec.xcframework, libavdevice.xcframework, libavfilter.xcframework, libavformat.xcframework, libavutil.xcframework, libswresample.xcframework, and libswscale.xcframework.
```

i'm facing issue with this package video_editor

Answer (score 0):

The issue that was raising on my end was of ffmpegkit package. so when I changed it to ffmpeg_kit_flutter_full it worked.

```
dependencies:
  ffmpeg_kit_flutter_full: ^4.5.1
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading my cocoapods back to 1.11.3 worked... Just a temporary fix for now